# Send signalr message from server to all clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

This is related to [SignalR + posting a message to a Hub via an action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549179/signalr-posting-a-message-to-a-hub-via-an-action-method), but my question is a bit different:

I'm on version 0.5.2 of signalr, using hubs. In older versions, you were encouraged to create methods on the hub to send messages to all clients, which is what I have:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        // Any other logic here
        Clients.messageRecieved(message);
    }

    ...
}
```

So in 0.5.2, I want to send a message to all the clients (say from somewhere in the controller). How can I get access to the `MyHub` instance?

The only way I've seen referenced is:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
hubContext.Clients.messageRecieved("hello");
```

Which is fine, but I want to call the method on my hub.

Comment: This is now possible in ASP.NET Core as well (although SignalR itself is still in alpha at the current time). See [this detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38832879/957950) on the Core version of this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by using a static method:

SignalR v.04-

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    internal static void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        var connectionManager = (IConnectionManager)AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IConnectionManager));
        dynamic allClients = connectionManager.GetClients<MyHub>();
        allClients.messageRecieved(message);
    }

    ...
}
```

SignalR 0.5+

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    internal static void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        context.Clients.messageRecieved(message);
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then call this like so:

```
MyHub.SendMessage("The Message!");
```

Good article on the SignalR API: http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/04/api-improvements-made-in-signalr-0-5.aspx

**Provided by Paolo Moretti** in comments

Comment: `AspNetHost.DependencyResolver` has disappeared in SignalR 0.5+. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/04/api-improvements-made-in-signalr-0-5.aspx) (Getting a reference to the connection/hub outside of a connection or hub)

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, in my example addNotification is client-side method:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalR.NotificationsHub>();
hubContext.Clients.addNotification("Text here");
```

On you client side you can add code to call your hub method in addNotification:

```
var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
notification.addNotification = function (message) {
 notification.addServerNotification(message); // Server Side method
}

$.connection.hub.start();
```

Hub:

```
 [HubName("notificationHub")]
    public class NotificationsHub : Hub
    {
        public void addServerNotification(string message)
        {
          //do your thing
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: 
Reading your question over and over agian I really don't find a reason to do that. Hub methods are usually there to be called from client side, or I misunderstood you, anyway here is an update. If you want to do a server side thing and then notify clients.

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Add(Item item)
  {
      MyHubMethodCopy(item);
      var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalR.NotificationsHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.addNotification("Items were added");

  }

  private void MyHubMethodCopy(Item item)
  {
      itemService.AddItem(item);
  }
```

Comment: The other response answers my question but you get a +1 because on reflection, I'm not sure I need to call a hub method - like you say 'hub methods are there to be used from client'

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to use hub methods. I was gonna do the same mistake. fixed it after this.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi what mistake?

Answer (score 2):

## Update for ASP.NET Core 2.x and 3.x:

You can easily access the Hub instance anywhere that you have Dependency Injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _myHubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<MyHub> myHubContext)
    {
        _myHubContext = myHubContext;
    }

    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        _myHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("MessageFromServer", msg);
    }
}
```

If it gives you syntax errors, make sure you have:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
```

and that you do NOT HAVE:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```