# SignalR call client methods from outside the Hub class AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to call client methods outside the hub on SignalR, the link below shows how to do this in the old version, although i'm unsure how to do this in the [SignalR ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) version. I've found a reference to a [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318209/asp-net-core-rc2-signalr-hub-context-outside-request-thread) and using a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Infrastructure.IConnectionManager although this namespace doesn't seem to existing anymore. An example would be great?

Old version: [How to call client methods and manage groups from outside the Hub class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-call-client-methods-and-manage-groups-from-outside-the-hub-class)

Comment: Check also solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller). It has more detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to inject `IHubContext<THub>` and then should be able to invoke methods.