# WebAPI - Application needs to display the table value changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using WebAPI , I have to monitor active status from database table

The column having active status only needs to shown in UI ( we dont know when exactly the user goes on active ) - so need a "monitor" application to show active users

But all example I can see with SignalR component with message broker example

Do we have any other way to do it ? any link or application code base would be great

Thanks 
Joe

Comment: Simple inject your hubcontext where you need it. Show for example there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849#46906849 . Then you can call from server a function on all connected clients.

Comment: let me try , but I am looking for alternative ways of using signalR