# Get Hub Context in SignalR Core from within another object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` (latest release) and would like to get the hub context from within another object that's not a `Controller`. In the "full" SignalR, I could use `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyCoolHub>();`

I have seen a lot of examples of just adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext<MyCoolHub>` as a parameter to the Ctor of a `Controller`, but no examples (that work) for otherwise.

**ETA:**

So, this is what I have working. Is this hacky?

```
public class MyHub : Hub
    public static IHubContext<MyHub> GlobalContext { get; private set; }
    public MyHub(IHubContext<MyHub> ctx){
        GlobalContext = ctx;
    }
}
```

Then I can call it as so:

```
await MyHub.GlobalContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync(...)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849#46906849 There is no difference if you do it out of a controller or another class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just set `IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext` on calling-side constructor.

I would recommend using .net core default DI container mechanism, not creating static property.

Please refer to [How do I get a reference to a Hub?](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/182#issuecomment-278421834)

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
}

public class CallingSideClass
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hubContext;

    public CallingSideClass(IHubContext<MyHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task FooMethod(...)
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync(...);
    }
}

public class Startup
{...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddScoped<CallingSideClass>();
    }
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So after looking over [this example](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/182#issuecomment-278421834) from the accepted answer, I didn't quite get where he was going, so I tried a few things and I think I got what he was saying. So, for folks who have this issue in the future, I want to change that example to a fully working example.

So we are going to create a "Shared Methods", like in the example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YouDontNeedToKnow.Core.Main.Hubs
{
    internal class HubMethods<THub> where THub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<THub> _hubContext;

        public HubMethods(IHubContext<THub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public Task InvokeOnGroupAsync(string groupName, string method, params object[] args) =>
            _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).InvokeAsync(method, args);

        public Task InvokeOnAllAsync(string method, params object[] args) =>
            _hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync(method, args);

        public Task AddConnectionIdToGroupAsync(string connectionId, string groupName) =>
            _hubContext.Groups.AddAsync(connectionId, groupName);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Hub` object, you add a constructor, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace YouDontNeedToKnow.Core.Main.Hubs
{
    internal class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public static string HubName => "myHub";

        private readonly HubMethods<MyHub> _hubMethods;

        public PlayerServicesHub(HubMethods<MyHub> hubMethods)
        {
            _hubMethods = hubMethods;
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Startup.cs`, you inject the shared class like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<HubMethods<MyHub>>();
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

This still works as it normally would:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider sp)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<MyHub>(MyHub.HubName);
    });
    app.UseMvc();
    // This is just an example line of how you can get the hub with context:
    var myHub = sp.GetService<HubMethods<MyHub>>();
}
```