# Getting the HubContext of a SignalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to get the `hubcontext` from a SignalR hub.

I want to be able to send notifications to the clients connected to that hub, while the hub instance may be disposed of.

The caveat is that I register the hubs dynamically, so I have the hub type as a Type object.

It is registered that way:

```
Application.UseSignalR(R => MapperMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(H).Invoke(R, new object [] { Path }));
```

With *H* being the hub type.

I have tried:

```
    var HubContext = ServiceProvider.GetService(H);
```

it returns null.

and I have tried:

```
    Application.Use(async (Context, Next) =>
    {
        var HubContext = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService(H);
    });
```

The lambda expression is not called.

I have read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2

and it is the one proposing the method above.

And I have also found this solution: [Get Hub Context in SignalR Core from within another object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393429/get-hub-context-in-signalr-core-from-within-another-object)

which can't work since I need to know the hubs at compile-time, which I don't since they come in the form of plug-ins, in external assemblies, and are found and registered with reflection.

All online posts and solutions revolve around the two methods above and don't work in this case.

How can I get the hub context then?