# Communication between two signalR Core Hubs

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have two signalR Core Typescript Apps (A & B)  with their own SignalR Core C# Hub (C & D).

No I want to trigger something from A in B. My plan was to send the trigger message from A to C, then C redirects it to D and sends it to B. The same should be possible in the other direction as well.

The Hubs are independent of each other, so making one Hub a part of the other doesnt work for me.
The only solution I came up with is to use two SignalR Core C# Clients to communicate between the Hubs, but that seems like a big overhead. Or is it the way to go?

Comment: Are both these hubs in the same solution? If so, couldn't you just inject your hub methods in to the other signalR hub instance? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393429/get-hub-context-in-signalr-core-from-within-another-object

Comment: @Andy Its not guaranteed that both Hubs run at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two signalR Core Typescript Apps (A & B) with their own SignalR Core C# Hub (C & D).

> No I want to trigger something from A in B.

You can refer to the following possible approaches to achieve above requirement.

***Approach 1:*** modify your implementation and merge existing functionality into single Hub class, then you can make SignalR Typescript client apps (A & B) connect to same hub server and communicate with each other.

***Approach 2:*** establish connections to both Hub C and Hub D on SignalR Typescript client apps (A & B) for each client user, so that user using Typescript client app A can also communicate with users from Typescript client app B.

***Approach 3:*** as you mentioned, install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client package and implement SignalR .NET client logic on Hub server project (A & B), which would make them act as both server and a SignalR .NET client.

***Approach 4:*** as @Kiril1512 mentioned, can implement SignalR .NET client logic in a  separate project that might be a queue-based (or servicebus-based etc) job. If user from SignalR Typescript client app A want to communicate to users from SignalR Typescript client app B connecting to Hub D, he can send specific message to Hub C to add a new queue message, then it will trigger that job to invoke Hub method of Hub server D to push message(s) to specific users from SignalR Typescript client app B, like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is a opinion question so it will be closed maybe.

But I believe the better approach is using something like `Service Bus`and implement event based communication. So something happens at A and you invoke hub method at C, then send a event to D and it will trigger via `signalR` the A. Using event bus will add the option to add for example another hub (E) that could receive those events and do something else.

Comment: There is nothing in this question that is opinion based.