# .NET Core SignalR redis backplain

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, signalr, blazor, stackexchange.redis

I have two sites, one in Blazor Server and other in Blazor Wasm, I need SignalR with redis to communicate both applications, but they are generating different channels. I read that both projects must have the same name. Is this the only way?

Comment: Check this thread: [Communication between two signalR Core Hubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451745/communication-between-two-signalr-core-hubs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought "AddStackExchangeRedis" took the project name from the startup project, but you just have to create a new project with the Hub implementation and then call it from each startup project, this generates the same channel name and you can communicate each other.