# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`1[IXXXX]' while attempting to activate 'XXXXX'

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, signalr

I define my strong typed SignalR hub exactly by MS Rules

```
public class OutputMessages : Hub<IOutputMessages>
{...}
```

than inject my SignalR hub to conctoller by the same way

```
public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
{
     public ApplicationAPIController(IHubContext<OutputMessages, IOutputMessages> _outputMessages)
     {...}
}
```

In Startup I add SignalR service as

```
        services.AddSignalR()
                .AddHubOptions<OutputMessages>(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                })
```

and define endpoint

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<OutputMessages>("/OutputMessages", options =>
                {
                   options.Transports =
                   HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                   HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                });

           });
```

Looks good? Yes. And compilation is good. But in runTime I receive

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[1]
      Error when dispatching 'OnConnectedAsync' on hub.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`1[IOutputMessages]' while attempting to activate 'OutputMessages'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubActivator`1.Create()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.OnConnectedAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler`1.RunHubAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler[6]
      OnConnectedAsync ending.
```

Comment: I don't think `.AddHubOptions<OutputMessages>(options =>...` is correct. change that to `services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);`, then try injecting `IOutputMessages` the normal route: `services.AddTransient<IOutputMessages, OutputMessages>();`

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393429/get-hub-context-in-signalr-core-from-within-another-object

Comment: in this case I receive in project initialization - 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IOutputMessages Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: OutputMessages': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`1[IOutputMessages]' while attempting to activate 'OutputMessages'.)'

Comment: The problem is that you have a constructor in your hub method to your `OutputMessages` class. You don't need any constructor since `AddSignalR` registers the HUB on DI. Then the dependency you resolve trough DI like I answered you in previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

and finally I found a solution

this is my strong type Hub definition

```
public class OutputMessages : Hub<IOutputMessages>
        {
            public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ConnectedUserList = new Dictionary<string, string>(1024);
            private readonly IHubContext<OutputMessages,IOutputMessages> _hubContext;
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
            private readonly ILogger<OutputMessages> _logger;

        public OutputMessages(IHubContext<OutputMessages, IOutputMessages> hubContext, ILogger<OutputMessages> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _db = dbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

....

        public async Task AdminMessages2(string userId, string message, bool consoleOnly)
        {
            string uname = await Username(userId);
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.AdminMessages2(userId, "API: " + uname + " " + message, consoleOnly);
        }

        [ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "id", Duration = 36000, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any)]
        public async Task<string> Username(string id)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = null;
            await Task.Run(() => user = _db.Users.Find(id));
            return user.UserName;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            string JWT = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            string ValidUserID = UserHelpers.ValidateJWT(JWT);
            if (ValidUserID != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"User {ValidUserID} connected to {this.GetType().Name} hub");
                if (ConnectedUserList.Any(x => x.Key == ValidUserID))
                {
                    ConnectedUserList.Remove(ValidUserID);
                }
                ConnectedUserList.Add(ValidUserID, Context.ConnectionId);
            }
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(System.Exception exception)
        {
            var JWT = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            string ValidUserID = UserHelpers.ValidateJWT(JWT);
            if (ValidUserID != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"User {ValidUserID} disconnected from {this.GetType().Name} hub");
                if (ConnectedUserList.Any(x => x.Key == ValidUserID))
                {
                    ConnectedUserList.Remove(ValidUserID);
                }
                ConnectedUserList.Add(ValidUserID, Context.ConnectionId);
            }
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

and this is injection Hub to controller

```
    public class ApplicationAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
         public ApplicationAPIController(ILogger<ApplicationAPIController> logger, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IConfiguration Configuration, CoreObjectDumper.CoreObjectDumper dump, IHubContext<OutputMessages, IOutputMessages> _outputMessages)
        {
 ...
```

definition of SignalR service in StartUp not changed. Problem is create Hub from class instead interface and Hub constructor must be exactly IHubContext<OutputMessages,IOutputMessages>