# Calling SignalR service from a BackgroundWorker in ABP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, backgroundworker, aspnetboilerplate

I have a BackgroundWorker which is supposed to broadcast something to all online clients in 5 seconds interval:

**DeactivationBackgroundWorker:**

```
public class DeactivationBackgroundWorker : PeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase, ISingletonDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<HitchRequest, long> _hitchRequestRepository;
    private readonly IHitchHub _hitchHub;

    public DeactivationBackgroundWorker(AbpTimer timer,
                                        IRepository<HitchRequest, long> hitchRequestRepository,
                                        IHitchHub hitchHub) : base(timer)
    {
        _hitchRequestRepository = hitchRequestRepository;
        Timer.Period = 5000;
        _hitchHub = hitchHub;
    }

    protected override async void DoWork()
    {
        await broadcastHitchRequestsAsync();
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    private async Task broadcastHitchRequestsAsync() {
        var activeHitchRequests = _hitchRequestRepository.GetAllList(p => p.IsActive);

        foreach (var hitchRequest in activeHitchRequests)
        {
            await _hitchHub.RequestHitch(hitchRequest.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

**IHitchHub:**

```
public interface IHitchHub: ITransientDependency
{
    Task RequestHitch(long hitchId);
}
```

**HitchHub:**

```
public class HitchHub : AbpCommonHub, IHitchHub
{
    private readonly IOnlineClientManager _onlineClientManager;

    public HitchHub(IOnlineClientManager onlineClientManager, IClientInfoProvider clientInfoProvider): base(onlineClientManager, clientInfoProvider)
    {
        _onlineClientManager = onlineClientManager;
    }

    public async Task RequestHitch(long hitchId)
    {
        var onlineClients = _onlineClientManager.GetAllClients();
        foreach (var onlineClient in onlineClients) {

            var signalRClient = Clients.Client(onlineClient.ConnectionId);

            await signalRClient.SendAsync("receiveHitch", hitchId);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know why the **Clients** in the HitchHub class is always null! Where should I initialize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `IHubContext<HitchHub>` instead of `IHitchHub`.

For example, see ABP's [SignalRRealTimeNotifier](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/097dacf2e2217273cb88f46f11df3257807d9572/src/Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR/AspNetCore/SignalR/Notifications/SignalRRealTimeNotifier.cs).

Related issue: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

**If your using Asp.net Core see:**

[Call SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849#46906849)

Otherwise:

**Hub's shouldn't be instantiated by yourself or any injection framework**

You have to use the ConnectionManager. For your code you should use:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HitchHub>().RequestHitch(hitchRequest.Id);
```

**Background information about Hub object lifetime: **

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server:

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its
>   methods from your own code on the server; all that is done for you by
>   the SignalR Hubs pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub
>   class each time it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a
>   client connects, disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them
>   to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the
>   server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your
>   Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple
>   connections and method calls, use some other method such as a
>   database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class
>   that does not derive from Hub. If you persist data in memory, using a
>   method such as a static variable on the Hub class, the data will be
>   lost when the app domain recycles.
>
> If you want to send messages to clients from your own code that runs
>   outside the Hub class, you can't do it by instantiating a Hub class
>   instance, but you can do it by getting a reference to the SignalR
>   context object for your Hub class. For more information, see How to
>   call client methods and manage groups from outside the Hub class later
>   in this topic.

See also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: From OP's previous questions, he's using ASP.NET Core.