# ABP real-time notification system background jobs

Tags: c#, redis, notifications, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

How can I get Online users at server side, to send notifications only to Online users, using a background job?

Background job:

```
public async Task SendNotifications()
{
    await _backgroundJobManager.EnqueueAsync<NotificationJob,
        UserIdentifier>(new UserIdentifier(_session.TenantId, _session.UserId.Value), delay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
}

public override void Execute(UserIdentifier args)
{
    var notifications = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(args);    
    Abp.Threading.AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notifications.ToArray()));
}
```

My Job is on a API where I don't have my *session* with user info, so I want to get all Online users to publish notifications only to them and after that call my job to notify them.

1. Does Module Zero by default uses Redis ? **As Alper said "No".**
2. I need to connect to SignalR on my API too ? **Adding `app.MapSignalR();` to my WebApi `startup`seems to work, but sometimes doesn't, I am missing something**
3. How can I get Online users at web api (server side) ? **An alternative I found was to get all subscriptions (`GetSubscriptionsAsync`) and there I have my userId to send the notifications. var onlineClients = _onlineClients.GetAllClients(); is returning null**

Thanks

Comment: for online users inject `IOnlineClientManager`. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration#online-clients

Comment: 1.Does Module Zero by default uses Redis ? (NO)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48980615/calling-signalr-service-from-a-backgroundworker-in-abp

Comment: Sorrry, What a mean by server side is from an API. Doing from my website server side is working, but when I move my code to a web api doesn’t work, 2 reasons: No session info(user and tenant) and i cant get online clients when I call my notifier (IOnlineClientManager).

Comment: so create a new API method in your abp project that gives you online users.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu but How I get those online users that are connected to signalr hub?

Comment: IOnlineClientManager https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-Integration#online-clients

Comment: Sometimes the background job runs and sometimes not, using Hangfire or not. And sometimes `IOnlineClientManager` has users and sometimes not. I am missing some configuration ? Do I need `app.MapSignalR();`at both WebSite and WebApi ?

Comment: Noting yet, my signalr and background job is intermittent,

Comment: Yes, we took a different approach, not using jobs anymore . thanks