# ASP.NET core SignalR - hub Negotiate - Err_Connection_Refused

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working with SignalR for the first time and trying to connect to hub from Angular. I am trying to implement the same in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608491/using-signalr-core-to-send-messages-from-a-controller-method-to-angular)

I am not sure where this negotiate comes from

OPTIONS http://localhost:5001/messageHub/negotiate net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here is my code.

```
public startConnection = () => {
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl('http://localhost:5001/messageHub')
  .build();

this.hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => alert('Connection started'))
  .catch(err => alert('Error while starting SignalR connection: ' + err));
}
```

Here is appsettings.Development.json

```
 "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}},
"SignalR": {
"messageHub": "http://localhost:5001/messageHub"
  },
"Api": {
"GenerateTokenUrl": "http://localhost:5000/api/Values"
 }
```

It is giving me this error in Chrome Dev tools[image: messageHub Negotiate]

Comment: Shouldn't the port be 5000 and not 5001? Try it out.

Comment: Nope, its still the same error with 5000

Comment: Share us your `startup.cs`? Does angular and signalR in the same project? If not, try to enable cors in signalR project.

Comment: Have you been able to make it works ?