# In ASP.NET Core SignalR, how do I send a message from the server to a client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I've successfully setup a SignalR server and client using the newly released ASP.NET Core 2.1. I built a chat room by making my `ChatHub` extend `Hub`: whenever a message comes in from a client, the server blasts it back out via `Clients.Others`.

What I do not yet understand is how to send a message to clients *not* as a response to an incoming message. If the server is doing work and produces a result, how do I gain access to the `Hub` in order to message particular clients? (Or do I even need access to the `Hub`? Is there another way to send messages?)

Searching this issue is difficult as most results come from old versions of ASP.NET and SignalR.

Comment: Have not tried it myself, but this video could be what you need: [Realtime notification using SignalR in asp net core mvc application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bqTmD5Tpjc)

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/182

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can inject the `IHubContext<T>` class into a service and call the clients using that.

```
public class NotifyService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hub;

    public NotifyService(IHubContext<ChatHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public Task SendNotificationAsync(string message)
    {
        return _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
}
```

Now you can inject the `NotifyService` into your class and send messages to all clients:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly NotifyService _service;

    public SomeClass(NotifyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return _service.SendNotificationAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be a bit naive with regard to ASP here, but how does that service help me send a message? If I have some `HandleEvent` function out elsewhere in my code (outside most of ASP land), how would I access this service, instantiate it, and use it?

Comment: Based on your question I thought you were trying to send a message from a different part of an ASP app. If you are trying to do if from a different project/application then you would need to call an API to send the message for you. If you have some example code of what you are trying to do that might help make things clearer

Comment: I fixed my understanding of how ASP.NET services work, and now this answer makes significantly more sense. I think this is what I need.

Comment: Couple changes: `InvokeAsync` is now `SendAsync` (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1300) and make sure to add the namespace `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;` in order to get the extension methods needed. See also https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2239

Answer (score 4):

**Simple inject the hubcontext into the class where you use the hubcontext.**

Details you will find there:

[Call SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849#46906849)

Answer (score 2):

There are now official Microsoft Docs for the SignalR HubContext that answer your question
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1

But yes, as others have pointed out, you need to get an instance of IHubContext via dependency injection to access hub methods outside of the hub.