# Firing SignalR Core message

Tags: signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a `SignalR` hub, the goal is to monitor the progress of a long running job (several hours) and as it progresses everyone monitoring the progress gets updates.

What I'm trying to do is figure out the best way to send a message to a `SignalR` without being 'connected' to it as a client.

I've been trying to search docs to see if there's a way to inject `SignalR` into another controller or class just to send messages without being 'connected'... but I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just inject typed hubcontext.**

Details see here:
[Call SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849?noredirect=1#comment87759673_46906849)