# SignalR missing connection in HubCallerContext

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-2.0

Trying to do simple chat and sending user to the userTracker when he/she is connected

```
 public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var user = Helper.GetUserInformationFromContext(Context);
        await this.userTracker.AddUserAsync(Context.Connection, user);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UsersJoined", new UserInformation[] { user });
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("SetUsersOnline", await GetOnlineUsersAsync());

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

but in the old versions HubCallerContext is like this :

public HubCallerContext(HubConnectionContext connection);

```
    public HubConnectionContext Connection { get; }
    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
    public string ConnectionId { get; }
```

the version I am using ( 2.3.0 ) is like

```
 protected HubCallerContext();


    public abstract string ConnectionId { get; }

    public abstract string UserIdentifier { get; }

    public abstract ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }

    public abstract IFeatureCollection Features { get; }

    public abstract CancellationToken ConnectionAborted { get; }



    public abstract void Abort();
```

So how can I get the missing Connection ?

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: I am sending all connected user to Task AddUserAsync(HubConnectionContext connection, UserInformation info); this but the problem is there is I dont have public HubCallerContext(HubConnectionContext connection); in my version @davidfowl

Comment: What I meant was, what do you need from HubConnectionContext?

Comment: I need the current IHubProtocol name...

Answer (score 0):

You simple have to inject it where you use it

Sample:

```
public class YourClassWhereYouNeedHubContext 
{
// Inject into constructor
public YourClassWhereYouNeedHubContext (IHubContext<VarDesignHub> hubcontext)
{
    HubContext = hubcontext;
    ...
}

private IHubContext<VarDesignHub> HubContext
{
    get;
    set;
}
}
```

Then you can also call

```
await this.HubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Completed", id);
```

Please read also:

[Call SignalR Core Hub method from Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller/46906849#46906849)