# SignalR Hubs through Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, ninject, signalr-hub

I have a look at many examples on several web pages and finally getting very confused due to the different approach on each of the examples. I simply want to use a HubBase class where I define shared hub methods i.e. OnConnected(), AddToGroup()) and multiple hub classes (HubX, HubY) where I define specific methods to these hubs. Here is the basic structure I try to apply:

***ITypedHubClient:***

```
public interface ITypedHubClient
{
    Task BroadcastData(string groupName, object data);
}
```

***HubBase:***

```
public class HubBase : Hub<ITypedHubClient>
{
    public readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        //
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        //
    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(string connectionId, string groupName)
    {
        //
    }


    public async Task SendMessageToAll(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(user, message);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToGroup(string groupName, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync(message);
    }
}
```

***HubX:***

```
[HubName("hubX")]
public class HubX : HubBase
{
    private readonly static IHubContext context = 
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubX>();

    public static async Task SendDataToGroup(string groupName, object data)
    {
        await context.Clients.Group(groupName).refreshData(data);
    }

    public static async Task BroadcastData(object data)
    {
        await context.Clients.Group("groupX").refreshData(data);
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public class MyController : Controller

    private IHubContext<HubX> hubContext;

    public MyController(IHubContext<HubX> hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public JsonResult Create()
    {
        //...  
        this.hubContext.Clients.Group("groupX").BroadcastData("groupX", data);
    }
```

My question is that:

**1)** What changes should be made in order to use DI and use base Hub class properly?

**2)** Should I call the hub methods from Controller? Or Hub class (HubX, Y)? I mean that in some examples, `hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessageToAll(message)` methods are called from the Controller directly while in some of them calls the method in the Hub class i.e. `HubX.SendMessageToAll(message);`. Any idea about which one is best practice?

**3)** Should I inherit Hub from Hub or HubBase class?

**Note:** If you have idea only one of the questions above, it is also ok for me and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which example shows `HubX.SendMessageToAll(message)`? I've never seen that. Sounds like a static method.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use `static` methods in `HubX`. Then in your controller, change the type of context you're asking from DI:

```
public MyController(IHubContext<HubX> hubContext)
```

2) Use `hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessageToAll(message)`. The other way seems like it's using static methods, which I can see going wrong sometimes. SignalR isn't designed to work that way.

3) You decide. It depends on if you want it to inherit the methods from `HubBase` or not.

Comment: Dear Gabriel, many thanks for your reply. I updated ITypedHubClient and Controller according to your suggestions as shown above. Could you please have a look at and let me know is there any update needed?

Comment: Here is my questions: **1)** Is `HubBase : Hub<ITypedHubClient>` and `HubX : HubBase` inheritences in HubBase and HubX classes are true?

Comment: **2)** In the examples I follow, there is no implementation of `BroadcastData()` method defined in `ITypedHubClient` class. Is there any mistake? If so, should I implement it in `HubBase`?

Comment: **3)** How can I use the methods e.g. `SendMessageToAll()` in the `HubBase`? Should I also define them in the  `ITypedHubClient` interface and access via that interface? As a result, could you please update your reply by using my code and by defining the missing parts? Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: 1) That's fine, if that's what you want to do. 2) That's up to you. 3) `SendMessageToAll()` is defined in `HubBase`, so there's nothing stopping you from using it in `HubBase`. Just call it: `await SendMessageToAll(something)`

Comment: You still have static methods in `HubX`, which is unecessary. None of those methods should be static. If you remove `static`, you can just call `await Clients.Group(groupName).refreshData(data);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think I am really confused with the methods on Client vs Server side calls. So, the approach on the answer of that page is true (regarding to client and server side methods)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717449/call-signalr-method-from-controller-net-core-2-1

Comment: Right. In your case, `ITypedHubClient` defines the methods that the client accepts, and `HubX` and `HubBase` define the methods the server accepts.

Comment: Ahaaa, for this reason the implementation of these methods in ITypedHubClient are in JavaScript side, is that true? If so, I am really surprised, because I asken this question to my self many time :)) In that example, DoSomething() method will be implemented in JavaScript side, true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197050/discussion-between-hexadecimal-and-gabriel-luci).