# Simple Injector registration problem in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, signalr, dependency-resolver

I set DI in my Controller as shown below and tied to register IHubContext as it seen on

***Controller:***

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<DemoHub> context;

    public DemoController(IHubContext<DemoHub> context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

***Global.asax:***

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();



    container.Register<IHubContext, IHubContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // or 

    container.Register<IHubContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // code omitted
}
```

But when I debug my app, encounter "*System.ArgumentException: 'The given type IHubContext is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type. Parameter name: TImplementation'*" error. So, how can I register IHubContext properly?

Comment: Version of Aspnet? Core, Framework? Version of SignalR?

Comment: @JamieRees .Net Framework 4.8, ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7.0, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.4.1.0.

Comment: You have to register the implementation with the container in order for it to be injected when resolving dependents

Comment: @Nkosi How can I do this? Could you pls post it as answer? Sorry, but I have really no idea about that and I have tried many thing to fix the problem. Thanks...

Comment: @Nkosi Any help please?

Comment: Youneed to start by reviewing the documentation that matches the version you are using. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Comment: I had already reviewed and tried some suggestion. But get "*The given type IHubContext<DemoHub> is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.*" error.

Comment: @JamieRees Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ASP.NET MVC` doesn't have built in dependency injection for `SignalR` hub context you have to obtain a context instance using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager`. With this you can register a dependency with your container that creates `IHubContext` instance. Considering you have typed hub

```
public class DemoHub : Hub<ITypedClient>
{
}
```

and interface

```
public interface ITypedClient
{
    void Test();
}
```

register dependency as the following

```
container.Register<IHubContext<ITypedClient>>(() =>
{
    return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<DemoHub, ITypedClient>();
}, Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

And the controller should look like

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<ITypedClient> context;

    public DemoController(IHubContext<ITypedClient> context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. Actually I tried to use ITypedClient at first, but as I use .NET MVC (rather than .NET Core) I cannot use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR
and have to use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR dll. For this reason I cannot pass ITypedClient to the Controller as I mentioned on [SignalR : How to use IHubContext<THub,T> Interface in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250585/signalr-how-to-use-ihubcontextthub-t-interface-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: In this scene, I cannot use ITypedClient and only pass `IHubContext<DemoHub>` to the Controller. I tried your answer for this usage as `container.Register<IHubContext<JiraHub>>` and 
`return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JiraHub, IHubContext>()` but encounter the following error: "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext>' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IHubContext<DemoHub>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*"

Comment: @hexadecimal I've updated my answer. Pay attention that you should use `IHubContext<>` with client interface and **not** with hub class

Comment: You rock!.. Thanks a lot for your helps and wonderful explanations... The problem was solved now and I can proceed to complete my SignalR implementation :)