# Options Other than SignalR to push info to a specific Client via .Net Core?

Tags: .net, signalr, webhooks, signalr-hub

**Scenario:** I am waiting for webhook to hit my controller endpoint in .Net Core thereby confirming a payment by the customer to a third party. Ideally I would like this controller to trigger a message I send specifically to the customer who paid.

**Problem:** From what I'm reading I cannot call a hub method (SignalR) from my controller unless I intend to send to all clients.  While my hub is tracking users via a dictionary of unique ids, I'm assuming that injecting a hub context as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller) will create a new instance of the hub without access to the existing ids in the hub that's running.  Are there any other options for pushing a message to a specific client after receiving the webhook confirmation to my controller?

Comment: *From what I'm reading...* Could you include the source?

Comment: @PeterBons this is just me reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller

Comment: @JonnyMac can you add the customer to a group on connecting and only send the message to that signalr group?

Comment: @97ldave that's worth trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution for me is to create the payment through the hub (instead of a normal rest API) and pass the connectionId (The hub has a dictionary of userId and connectionId) for the client as information to be passed back by the third party webhook. This way when I receive the webhook call I also get the connectionId to reference when I call the hub service like this:

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionID).SendAsync("CompletePayment", transactionId);
```