# How can you show a message posted with signalr on a specific/different page than from where its submitted?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

When a song request is made on the index page, and the submit button is pressed, I want the request to end up on the djpage instead. Is this possible? I have rather limited signalr and JS skills so I've been stumbling through the dark trying to figure this out.

Let's say we're working with the signalr tutorial on microsofts page for the sake of clarity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

This is the hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
@page
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-1">User</div>
            <div class="col-5"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-1">Message</div>
            <div class="col-5"><input type="text" class="w-100" id="messageInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-6 text-end">
                <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-6">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

And this is the JS:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable the send button until connection is established.
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    // We can assign user-supplied strings to an element's textContent because it
    // is not interpreted as markup. If you're assigning in any other way, you 
    // should be aware of possible script injection concerns.
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message}`;
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Is it possible to somehow make the message posted show on the djpage INSTEAD of the index page? If so, how would this be done? If not, what can be done to emulate this type of behavior?

Comment: dj page means `django` ? if so , can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251538/emitting-signal-from-server-to-the-clients-in-python-django-like-signalr) help you?

Comment: signalr server and client can match with each other, [any supported client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/client-features?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can safely connect to any supported server, and any compatibility issues would be considered bugs to be fixed. If you want to find a signalr client for python, can [this](https://pypi.org/project/signalr-client/) help you?

Answer (score 0):

> When a song request is made on the index page, and the submit button is pressed, I want the request to end up on the djpage instead. Is this possible?

If you'd like to send ordered song from user page to dj page, you can try to add dj into a group, and then you can send song request (message) to dj page by sending message to that specific group, like below.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task OrderSong(string name, string songname)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", name, songname);

        await Clients.Group("djgroup").SendAsync("ReceiveNewSongOrder", name, songname);
    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
```

On dj page

```
<h1>DJ Page</h1>

<ul id="OrderList"></ul>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

        connection.on("ReceiveNewSongOrder", function (user, message) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            document.getElementById("OrderList").appendChild(li);
            li.textContent = `${user} ordered song '${message}'`;
        });

        connection.start().then(function () {
            //add DJ to a specific group
            connection.invoke("AddToGroup", 'djgroup').catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    </script>
    }
```

On user page

```
<h1>User Page</h1>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-2">Your Name</div>
            <div class="col-5"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-2">Song Name</div>
            <div class="col-5"><input type="text" class="w-100" id="messageInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-7 text-end">
                <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Order A Song" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-6">
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

        //Disable send button until connection is established
        document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
            li.textContent = `${user} order a song: ${message}`;
        });

        connection.start().then(function () {
            document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });

        document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
            connection.invoke("OrderSong", user, message).catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

[image]