# How to get connection id from a controller?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have this hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<User> connections = new ConnectionMapping<User>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var user = GetUser();
        connections.Add(user, Context.ConnectionId);

        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, user.GroupId.ToString());

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public string GetConnectionId(User user)
    {
        return connections.GetConnections(user).First();
    }

    private User GetUser() {}
}
```

And in a controller I'm doing:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

context.Clients.Groups(user.GroupId.ToString()).Notify();
```

But the above sends to all users of the group. How can I send it to just the user that currently made the request?

Note:
I'm calling the method from outside the hub.

Comment: Now I understand what you are asking, but I am afraid that this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534505/call-hub-method-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Hub method in c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534505/call-hub-method-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To send a specific update to a specific client, you'll need the connectionId. The group is for a broadcast as you already know.

Since you're accessing from outside the Hub in a separate controller, you do not have access to the current Context.ConnectionId.

But since you do have the hubContext, you could send an update to a specific connection if you can get a hold of the connectionId of the user you want to send an update to, using something like:

```
   context.Clients.Client(connectionid).Notify()
```

In your case, make your GetConnectionId as static:

```
    public static string GetConnectionId(User user)
    {
      return connections.GetConnections(user).First();
    }
```

then, send a notify to the specific connection of the user:

```
    var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    context.Clients.Groups(NotificationHub.GetConnectionId(user)).Notify();
```

That should work.