# How to use SignalR with QueueBackgroundWorkItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a WebApi2 controller method that starts a long-running background process:

```
public IHttpActionResult LongProcess()
{
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
    {
        myService.RunLongProcess(ct);
    });

    return Ok();
}
```

The `RunLongProcess` is a method within a separate `Services` assembly. I'm also using `SignalR` in my project but currently for other purposes. `SignalR`is only located in the main WebApi project

How can I use `SignalR`to push notifications back to the client from the service method?

Should I start the hub in the action (within the `HostingEnvironment` block and then pass a callback delegate to the method, which in turn will use `SignalR` to push notifications?

Comment: You can just call hub methods from your background process, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395201/call-a-hub-method-from-a-controllers-action).

Comment: @mason Yes I know I need to call hub methods from within the controller action. But the actual work is done in the server method and I need to pass info back to the action.

Comment: No, I'm not saying to do to the work from the controller action. I'm saying to do the work from the background method. The code to do it from a controller action vs a server method is the same either way, which is why I linked to that answer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr