# Triggering signalr hub methods, outside of the hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I need to implement some push notfications for my asp.net core 2.2 site.
I found signalr, and started looking at it. I have tried implementing a small toy example, and I now have a hub class that looks as so:

As simple as can be. I now have a controller from which I need to trigger a push notification on the client computer. which could be triggered by thus controller being hit (In my real project, I need to send a push notification when a user is online, and when a new article is published on my site).
So here is my controller:

```
public class msgController : Controller
{
public IActionResult Index()
{
return Content("serving content");
}
}
```

But I now need to somehow trigger my hub's sendMessage function. I'm able to call it if I just put the hub inside the controller, like this:

```
public class msgController : Controller
{
private IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hub;
public msgController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
{
_hub = hub;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "bruger", "besked");
return Content("serving content");
}
}
```

But I would like to use my actual Hub class, and also, none of the docs that I can find do it like this. How could I do this?

I've seen some places giving [answers tha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395201/call-a-hub-method-from-a-controllers-action)t does'nt really make a lot of sense to me, like just accessing the contexthub, through a  GlobalHost, that is'nt available to me.  Other places claim that this j[ust is'nt possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904678/call-signalr-core-hub-method-from-controller).

So how do I call/trigger my hub, and send a message to the client?
Also, the version of my site where the hub is just written in the controller works now, and a sendmesage() function is called. But I can't really see the message being sent clientside. Where can I find it?

Comment: GlobalHost is not available in .net core, this is a .net full signalR version. What's wrong with IHubContext injection? this is exactly the way to do what you want.

Comment: hmm, it's because I want my hub to contain all the other methods assoicated with the hub. Things like onconnected and so on

Comment: Also I want to define my own functions in my hub class

Comment: Well, you simply can't get the Hub without the HubContext. Go with the answer by @Kiril1512 or wrap your hub in another class (inject it with HubContext). Add to the wrapper the methods you need and than use the wrapper everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to declare an interface with your hub methods like:

```cs
public interface ISignalRHub
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcasts the chart data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chartData">The chart data.</param>
    Task BroadcastChartData(List<ChartModel> chartData);

    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcasts the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
    Task BroadcastMessage(string message);

    /// <summary>
    /// Broadcasts the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The chat message.</param>
    Task BroadcastMessage(ChatMessage message);
}
```

and define it in the hub:

```cs
public class SignalRHub : Hub<ISignalRHub>
```

then after injecting it in the controller:

```cs
public msgController(IHubContext<SignalRHub, ISignalRHub> hub)
{
  _hub = hub;
}
```

So if you want send a message to client just create a method in the hub and declare it in your interface. Because with `IHubContext` you can't directly call a specific hub method or client.

As said in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0#get-an-instance-of-ihubcontext-in-middleware):

> When client methods are called from outside of the Hub class, there's no caller associated with the invocation. Therefore, there's no access to the ConnectionId, Caller, and Others properties.

Comment: You can see this signalr example project, soon I will add an push notifications example: https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo

Comment: really cool project! There is one thing though. I can't seem to figure out where the sending of messages actually happens? I can find the hub class, but I can't find anywhere where it seems like the message is sent

Comment: On the worked example it happens with `await this.hub.Clients.All.BroadcastChartData(DataManager.GetData());` so in the client side there is a signalR listner that is listening on the method like: 
`private addMessageListener = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on('BroadcastMessage', (message: Message) => {
      this.message = message;
      this.messages.push(this.message);
      console.log(message);
    });
  }`