# SignalR: How to truly call a hub's method from the server / C#

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm trying to improve my application which will require calling a hub from C# instead of javascript.  The current workflow for adding a task in my app is:

- make an API call to add the data to the database
- return new record to AngularJS controller
- invoke hub's method from controller
- hub broadcasts call to clients appropriately

What I would like to do is bypass calling the hub's method from my AngularJS controller and call it directly from my API controller method.

This is what my hub currently looks like:

```
public class TaskHub : Hub
{
    public void InsertTask(TaskViewModel task)
    {
        Clients.Caller.onInsertTask(task, false);
        Clients.Others.onInsertTask(task, true);
    }
}
```

There are many SO threads out there on the topic, but everything I've read would have me adding the following code to my API controller:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TaskHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.onInsertTask(task);
```

There are number of issues with this.  First and foremost, I want the client broadcast calls to exist in a single class, not called directly from my API controller(s).  Secondly, `hubContext` is an instance of `IHubContext` rather than `IHubCallerConnectionContext`.  This means I only have access to all clients and couldn't broadcast different responses to the `Caller` and `Others` like I'm currently doing.

Is there a way to *truly* call a hub's method from C# and, ideally, have access to the different caller options?  Ideally, I'd be able to do something as easy as the following from my API controller (or better yet, a solution with DI):

```
var taskHub = new TaskHub();
taskHub.InsertTask(task);
```

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

For posterity, I thought I'd include my full solution as per Wasp's suggestion.

First, I modified my javascript (AngularJS) service to include the SignalR connection ID in a custom request header for the API call, in this case an INSERT:

```
var addTask = function (task) {
    var config = { 
        headers: { 'ConnectionId': connection.id } 
    };
    return $http.post('/api/tasks', task, config);
};
```

Then, I retrieved the connection ID from the request in my API controller after performing the applicable CRUD operation and then called my hub:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]TaskViewModel task)
{
    var viewModel = taskAdapter.AddTask(task);
    var connectionId = request.Headers.GetValues("ConnectionId").FirstOrDefault();
    TaskHub.InsertTask(viewModel, connectionId);
    return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, viewModel);
}
```

My hub looks like this where I'm now only using static methods called from my API controller:

```
public class TaskHub : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TaskHub>();

    public static void InsertTask(TaskViewModel task, string connectionId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionId))
        {
            context.Clients.Client(connectionId).onInsertTask(task, false);
            context.Clients.AllExcept(connectionId).onInsertTask(task, true);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Clients.All.onInsertTask(task, true);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a conditional statement in my hub method to handle if the hub call wasn't initiated from the client side portion of my app.  This would be if an external app/service called my API.  In such a situation, a SignalR connection and of course "ConnectionId" header value would not exist.  In my case, though, I still would want to call the `onInsertTask` method for all connected clients which informs them of the data change.  This should never happen, but I just included it for completeness.

Comment: In the context of your API call SignalR doesn't know which client is the "Caller".  Normally SignalR calls go over their own connection which has that context.

Comment: I did consider that when thinking about the issue with being able to choose the broadcast audience.  I wasn't sure if there was a way to "attach" the caller the API call, but (thinking aloud) I guess you'd then need to start your connection/hub on the client side anyway.  In cases where the caller/audience doesn't matter, I think one should still be able to call a hub's method from C# (an API controller in my case)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to *truly* call a hub method, as you call it, you have to be connected to it, and call over that connection. By calling something different (your API) you cannot do that kind of call, and therefore you have to resort to the *server initiated* broadcasting capabilities, which by nature cannot know about what the `Caller` is because there's no SignalR's caller.

That said, if your client calling the API (no matter if it's Javascript or C#) is already connected to the hub when performing the call, you can always *decorate* your call towards the API with the `connectionId` of your hub's connection (by query string, by headers, ...). If your API receives that information, it can then *simulate* the `Caller` API with

```
Clients.Client(connectionId)
```

and it can do the same for `Others` with

```
Clients.AllExcept(connectionId)
```

over a `IHubContext` instance. Check the [official docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients).

You can then follow the suggestion from DDan about encapsulating the `IHubContext` usage in a convenient centralized way, or even restructure it a bit to make it easily DI-compliant.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to successfully use your suggestion to implement a solution and included it in my question for posterity. :)

Comment: @im1dermike just for the sake of clarity, why did you unaccept this answer after having said that it worked and you built a working solution on top of it? More important, the accepted answer does not explain how to determine who's the caller from a non-SignalR method, which is what the OP asks. That is "a" solution, perfectly valid but not matching what the OP sets as the context, so I don't see how it applies. The main point is not to "keep my points", it is to have an answer matching the OP, not what you ended up doing.

Comment: No idea how that happened. I didn't purposefully change it. Perhaps someone else did? In either case, I just corrected the matter. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem, I was just a bit confused :)

Answer (score 3):

I am using the method explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549179/signalr-posting-a-message-to-a-hub-via-an-action-method/31063193#31063193) answer.

```
public class NewsFeedHub : Hub 
{
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NewsFeedHub>();

    // Call this from JS: hub.client.send(channel, content)
    public void Send(string groupName, string content)
    {
        Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(content);
    }

    // Call this from C#: NewsFeedHub.Static_Send(groupName, content)
    public static void Static_Send(string groupName, string content)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(content);
    }

}
```

The hub defines and uses its hubContext, so you can do:

```
var newsFeedHub = new NewsFeedHub();
var newsFeedHub.Static_Send("ch1", "HELLO");
```

Or:

```
var taskHub = new TaskHub();
var taskHub.InsertTask(task);
```

If you prefer that, based on your method naming.

Comment: I replaced to `groupName` and `Client.Gourp(groupName)`.
I think in your case the combination of `Clients.Client(connectionId)` and `Clients.AllExcept(connectionId)` will work just fine.