# SignalR using Web API and Calling Service on other server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have an application that makes calls from the client using JQuery to a Web API controllers, but then from such controller is makes a call to another server, where another controller picks up and does all the data logic (insertions, etc..) so basically (two different solutions and totally separate, no dependencies)

```
Client
Web API   (this live in http://localhost:5020/)
-----------------
Some Server API here  (this lives in http://localhost:4566)
Data Layer

SQL
```

So Web API makes calles to some server and saves or retrieves data.

I need to be able to add SinalR when something is saved to one of the databases on the other server. How can I design this so I get notifications something was saved in the client side since there are no dependencies?.

Do i add the HUBs and what not on the receiving server or on the client server, a bit confuse how that would work.

I would appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the method explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549179/signalr-posting-a-message-to-a-hub-via-an-action-method/31063193#31063193).

This will allow you to have hubs which can be invoked from frontend (JS) and backend (C#) as well.
Basically for the backend (C#) calls use a hubcontext. As explained by the SignalR team [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) too.

Simple code (in your hub class):

```
public class YourHubClass: Hub 
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHubClass>();

    // ...
    public static void Send(string message) {
        hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Now you can call the static method in your controller:

```
YourHubClass.Send("Hello!");
```

And the clients will receive the message by the event `addMessage(message)`